# Please help me to fix Pip command not found in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, package, command

I'm working on a project call "Dolphin The New Assistant" using python and I really need these modules
Libraries:
speech_recognition
wikipedia
time,datetime
json
smtplib
os,sys
re
youtube_search
gTTs
but by somehow, when I type "pip install (these packages)" it said pip is not a valid command and it doesn't found on my laptop
please help me to fix the problem
thank you

Comment: A lot of unanswered questions: what OS are you using.; how was python installed; where is python installed (which python), are there multiple versions of python installed . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have pip installed. Depending on your OS (either Windows or MacOS), run the following in your terminal:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```